# Is there an equivalent of FireMonkey's TAniIndicator for the VCL?

Tags: delphi, vcl

Is there an equivalent of FireMonkey's `TAniIndicator` for the VCL?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TActivityIndicator` looks like what you are after:
http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Rio/en/Vcl.WinXCtrls.TActivityIndicator

Comment: thanks uwe :) sad that we can not customize the background color of the TactivityIndicator :(

Comment: As the control is drawn transparent, you should be able to make it a child of a TPanel with that color.